# scala spark use expr to value inside a column

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to add a new column to a dataframe with a boolean value, evaluating a column inside the dataframe. For example, I have a dataframe of

```
+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+----------------+
|colA|colB|colC|colD|colE|colPRODRTCE|         colCOND|
+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+----------------+
|   1|   1|   1|   1|   3|         39|colA=1 && colB>0|
|   1|   1|   1|   1|   3|         45|          colD=1|
|   1|   1|   1|   1|   3|        447|colA>8 && colC=1|
+----+----+----+----+----+-----------+----------------+
```

In my new column I need to evaluate if the expression of colCOND is true or false.

It's easy if you have something like this:

```
  val df = List(
    (1,1,1,1,3),
    (2,2,3,4,4)
  ).toDF("colA", "colB", "colC", "colD", "colE")

  val myExpression = "colA<colC"

  import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.expr

  df.withColumn("colRESULT",expr(myExpression)).show()

+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
|colA|colB|colC|colD|colE|colRESULT|
+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
|   1|   1|   1|   1|   3|    false|
|   2|   2|   3|   4|   4|     true|
+----+----+----+----+----+---------+
```

But I have to evaluate a different expression in each row and it is **inside the column colCOND.**

I thought in create a UDF function with all columns, but my real dataframe have a lot of columns. How can I do it?

Thanks to everyone

Comment: Do you have the solution ? I'm facing the exact same issue here.

Comment: @omnisius - please, see my answer. thank You.

Comment: I'm going to try that in Python, thank you a lot !

Answer (score 3):

if && change to AND, can try

```
package spark

import org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
import org.apache.spark.storage.StorageLevel.MEMORY_AND_DISK

object DataFrameLogicWithColumn extends App{
  val spark = SparkSession.builder()
    .master("local")
    .appName("DataFrame-example")
    .getOrCreate()

  import spark.implicits._

  val sourceDF = Seq((1,1,1,1,3,39,"colA=1 AND colB>0"),
    (1,1,1,1,3,45,"colD=1"),
    (1,1,1,1,3,447,"colA>8 AND colC=1")
  ).toDF("colA", "colB", "colC", "colD", "colE", "colPRODRTCE", "colCOND").persist(MEMORY_AND_DISK)


  val exprs = sourceDF.select('colCOND).distinct().as[String].collect()

  val d1 = exprs.map(i => {
    val df = sourceDF.filter('colCOND.equalTo(i))
    df.withColumn("colRESULT", expr(i))
  })

  val resultDF = d1.reduce(_ union _)

  resultDF.show(false)
  //  +----+----+----+----+----+-----------+-----------------+---------+
  //  |colA|colB|colC|colD|colE|colPRODRTCE|colCOND          |colRESULT|
  //  +----+----+----+----+----+-----------+-----------------+---------+
  //  |1   |1   |1   |1   |3   |39         |colA=1 AND colB>0|true     |
  //  |1   |1   |1   |1   |3   |447        |colA>8 AND colC=1|false    |
  //  |1   |1   |1   |1   |3   |45         |colD=1           |true     |
  //  +----+----+----+----+----+-----------+-----------------+---------+

sourceDF.unpersist()    
}
```

can try DataSet

```
    case class c1 (colA: Int, colB: Int, colC: Int, colD: Int, colE: Int, colPRODRTCE: Int, colCOND: String)

    case class cRes (colA: Int, colB: Int, colC: Int, colD: Int, colE: Int, colPRODRTCE: Int, colCOND: String, colResult: Boolean)

    val sourceData = Seq(c1(1,1,1,1,3,39,"colA=1 AND colB>0"),
      c1(1,1,1,1,3,45,"colD=1"),
      c1(1,1,1,1,3,447,"colA>8 AND colC=1")
    ).toDS()

    def f2(a: c1): Boolean={
      // we need parse value with colCOUND
      a.colCOND match {
        case "colA=1 AND colB>0" => (a.colA == 1 && a.colB > 0) == true
        case _ => false
      }
    }

    val res2 = sourceData
      .map(i => cRes(i.colA, i.colB, i.colC, i.colD, i.colE, i.colPRODRTCE, i.colCOND,
        f2(i)))
```

Comment: good but when we use collect on huge data it reduces performance. Can you please tell me any other solution

Comment: v1 - try persist(), unpersist()

Comment: v2 - try DataSet

Comment: case "colA=1 AND colB>0" => (a.colA == 1 && a.colB > 0) == true: 
- For All row this is common expression than This is not right way.
- How you will handle if 100s of possible conditions with respect to each row.
- I have doubt this will have performance issue for huge dataset meant for Spark